# Is aspnet_compiler.exe special?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnet-compiler, precompile

I'm attempting to make a ASP.NET compilation tool for a project I'm working on. Using aspnet_compiler does work perfectly fine, but a custom tool would suite our purposes a little bit better.

However, when I run the ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication method I get a "MissingManifestResourceException" complaining about "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture".

I then decompiled aspnet_compiler.exe and used its singular Precompiler.cs file which gave the same exception.

So its not my code since the same problem happens when I use aspnet_compiler.exe source code, but something else.

Any thoughts in what makes aspnet_compiler so special?

Comment: Curious to see how this turns out. I'll put a bounty out for you if you don't get an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're biting off more than you can probably chew trying to write your own ASP.NET compiler. If there's something special you need to do before or after compilation, look into using a *Pre* or *Post* build script.

[image]

Comment: But I'm not writing a compiler. Aspnet_compiler is just a wrapper about the ClientBuildManager class. I'm trying to do the same thing, just slightly customized. However at the moment, I can't replicate the aspnet_compiler tool even using its own source code.

Comment: Would a pre or post build script possibly suit your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the pre-compilation would have to be done after deployment of the web application, ie, at the client site. I'm told that there are some semi-third party modules that replace some of our files and thus would ruin the precompilation if we did it at build time.